# removing namespace std specifically sprintf in a denary to hex C++ program

Tags: c++, binary, hex, std

I have coded a denary to hex converter and am trying to find a way to remove the sprinf built in function as well as the stoi built in function that i used because as i am using c++ more i am told that using namespace std is bad practice but i cannot think of a way of doing this without breaking my program any help would be appreciated.

also i have left my comments in my code for future Questions should i remove these or leave them in when posting thankyou

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)

using namespace std;

int DecToHex(int Value) //this is my function 
{
char *CharRes = new (char); //crestes the variable CharRes as a new char 

//sprintf is part of the standard library 
sprintf(CharRes, "%X", Value);  
//char res is the place the concerted format will go 
//value is the value i want to convert    
//%X outputs a hex number        
//snprintf covers the formatting of a string                          

int intResult = stoi(CharRes); //stoi is a function in the library 

std::cout << intResult << std::endl; //print int results to the screen

return intResult; //returns int result 
}



int main()
{
int a;

std::cout << "Please enter a number" << std::endl;

std::cin >> a; //stores the value of a 

DecToHex(a); //runs the function 

system("pause"); //pauses the system 

return 0; //closes the program 
}
```

Comment: `std::cout << std::hex << Value << "\n";` There's no need to convert the vale to hex and back, it's the same value.

Comment: "*i am told that `using namespace std` is bad practice*" - yes, it is. "*but i cannot think of a way of doing this without breaking my program*" - you simply have to explicitly prefix `std::` in front of any symbol that belongs to the `std` namespace. `sprintf` -> `std::sprintf`, `stoi` -> `std::stoi`, etc, just like you already do for `std::cout`, `std::cin`, and `std::endl`.

Comment: @RetiredNinja can you please clarify what you mean by that a bit more

Comment: @RetiredNinja figured it out dont worry mate and thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

Stream in C++ already have built in function for converting format like decimal /hexa etc .. so you can just do this :

```
int main()
{
    int a;
    std::cout << "Please enter a number" << std::endl;

    std::cin >> a; //stores the value of a   
    std::cout << std::hex; // Set the formating to hexadecimal
    std::cout << a; // Put your variable in the stream
    std::cout << std::dec;, // Return the format to decimal. If you want to keep the hexa format you don't havr to do this
    std::cout << std::endl; // Append end line and flush the stream

    /* This is strictly equivalent to : */
    std::cout << std::hex << a << std::dec << std::endl;

    system("pause"); //pauses the system 
    return 0; //closes the program 
}
```

Using std::hex in the stream will print the value in hexa. Using std::dec will print the value in decimal format. Using std::octa will print the value in octal format.

You can call any function from the standard library without using `using namespace std` simply by prefixing the function with `std::`.
For example, `std::snprintf`, `std::stoi` etc..